# How to make a website home screen friendly?

Tags: html, ios, web, bookmarks, homescreen

If you add a bookmark on your home screen on an iPhone, you will see how different they are. Some, like BBC Future (https://bbc.com/future), look like an app when are opened, and some just redirect you to Safari.

How do I make a website that will look like an app in bookmark?

Thanks

Comment: favicons could be what you need.

Comment: @Harith no, I mean not favicons. They make just the icon look like an app. But here the whole website looks so

Comment: You can find more detail in the official documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/ConfiguringWebApplications/ConfiguringWebApplications.html https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/WebContent.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, you can found more detail in the official documentation about that: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/ConfiguringWebApplications/ConfiguringWebApplications.html
https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/WebContent.html